# Access Expression using a combo box to complete a text box

Tags: ms-access, expression, ms-access-2013

The expression:

```
=IIf(([cbo1]IS NOT NULL),DLookUp("[Thing1]","[tbl1]","[cbo1]= " & [Forms]![frm1]![cbo1]), "")
```

returns "#Error" when I try to use it to populate a text box based on the value of a combo box. The values in the combo box are all words, so setting

```
=IIF([cbo1]>0
```

in the first part creates a different error. I have this expression on a different part of the form and it works fine for numerical values.

```
=IIf(([txt1]>0),DLookUp("[thing1]","[tbl11]","[Thing2]= " & [Forms]![Frm1]![txt1]),"")
```

What am I missing on the one dealing with text?

Comment: I think you may have an "=" where "," should be before the dlookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IS NOT NULL` is supported in Access SQL, but not in VBA expressions.  Use `IsNull()`.

```vb
=IIf(Not IsNull([cbo1]), DLookUp("[Thing1]", "tbl1", "[cbo1]=" & [cbo1]), "")
```

Note the `DLookUp` expression requires that *tbl1* includes a numeric field named *cbo1*, the same as your combo box name. That could be correct, but it looks suspicious to me.  Double-check that field name if you get another error.